# Change the actual URL called in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-cloud, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to invoke the below method when the given route is called.
How do I modify/rewrite the path of the route?

URL in the postman/browser: "http://localhost:8080/compliance/status/{id}"

Actual URL to be called: [https://m.com/v1/myPage/getByBillOfLadingId/{id}](https://m.com/v1/myPage/getByBillOfLadingId/%7Bid%7D)

```
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/**")
                    .uri("https://m.com/v1/myPage/getByBillOfLadingId/"))
                    .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RewritePath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-rewritepath-gatewayfilter-factory) filter

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath(".*", "/v1/myPage/getByBillOfLadingId/"))
                        .uri("https://m.com"))
                .build();
    }
```

The [SetPath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-setpath-gatewayfilter-factory) filter may be useful as well.